# Group by a boolean variable and create a new column with the result for each group pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formula

This may be a litte confusing, but I have the following dataframe:

```
exporter assets   liabilities

False      5          1
True       10         8
False      3          1
False      24         20
False      40         2
True       12         11
```

I want to calculate a ratio with this formula `df['liabilieties'].sum()/df['assets'].sum())*100`

And I expect to create a new column where the values are the ratio but calculated for each boolean value, like this:

```
exporter assets   liabilities   ratio

False      5          1         33.3
True       10         8         86.3 
False      3          1         33.3
False      24         20        33.3
False      40         2         33.3
True       12         11        86.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `exporter` and `transform` the datafarme using `sum`, then use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) to divide `liabilities` by `assets` and use [`Series.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) to multiply by 100:

```
d = df.groupby('exporter').transform('sum')
df['ratio'] = d['liabilities'].div(d['assets']).mul(100).round(2)
```

Result:

```
print(df)
   exporter  assets  liabilities  ratio
0     False       5            1  33.33
1      True      10            8  86.36
2     False       3            1  33.33
3     False      24           20  33.33
4     False      40            2  33.33
5      True      12           11  86.36
```